# Are random effect variables automatically taken as factors in lmer (or lme) in R?

Tags: r, lme4, categorical-data, mixed-models, nlme

I understand that having a continuous or numeric variable as a **random effect** in a **mixed effects model** doesn't make much sense (e.g., see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105698/how-do-i-enter-a-continuous-variable-as-a-random-effect-in-a-linear-mixed-effect)).

But what I'm wondering is if `lme4::lmer` or `nlme::lme` in R purposefully prevent you from doing so...

Specifically, what I'm asking is: if I supply `lmer` (or `lme`) any non-factor (non-categorical) variable as a random effect, **does the function automatically treat it as a factor?**

Inserting `factor()` directly into lmer  (as is the usual method when using `lm`) produces the following error:

```
lmer(y ~ z + (1|factor(x)), data = dat)
Error: couldn't evaluate grouping factor factor(x) within model frame: try adding grouping factor to data frame explicitly if possible
```

Although the above error mentions adding a grouping factor directly to the data, it doesn't specify whether said grouping factor *needs* to be a factor (or is that perhaps implicit from the word choice)?

I understand it's fairly simple to just create a new factor class variable directly from my data, but I'm just curious if it's actually necessary when using `lmer` (or `lme`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem to matter.

```
library(lme4)

sl <- sleepstudy
sl$Subject <- as.numeric(levels(sl$Subject))[sl$Subject]

## subject as factor
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)

## subject as numeric
m2 <- update(m1, data = sl)

all.equal(VarCorr(m1), VarCorr(m2))
# TRUE
```

Checking the rest of the object, the call is different (which makes sense, I called the data frame something different), and the frame is different (due to the numeric vs. factor difference in Subject). Everything else is identical.

```
all.equal(m1, m2)
#[1] "Attributes: < Component “call”: target, current do not match when deparsed >"     
#[2] "Attributes: < Component “frame”: Component “Subject”: 'current' is not a factor >"
```

Grouping factors are subjected to `factorize()` within [`mkBlist()`](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/utilities.R#L57), which is called within [`mkReTrms()`](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/utilities.R#L116), which creates the model matrix for the random effects. `factorize()` is a helper that eventually calls `factor(x)` on right hand side terms in the random effects formula (conditional on whether it's already a factor, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It is a bit of a superficial answer (answering the bolded question "does the function automatically treat it as a factor?" rather than *why* calling a function within the RE part of the formula doesn't work). It's not something I understand well enough to comment on, would you want to add an answer about that?

Comment: @alexforrence thanks, Alex this is helpful. Where/how exactly did you determine your final paragraph ("Grouping factors...etc.)"?

Comment: @theforestecologist generally from the source at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/utilities.R, is there a specific bit that doesn't make sense?

Comment: @alexforrence No I just didn't know how to do that on my own :p.